# Someone claims I plagiarized my own question. What are my options if deletion is no longer possible?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

I have posted a question a few months ago and I would like to get it deleted.

In the question I have posted my own opinion and views that I have used in an essay. I have been told that there have been some similarities found using the [Turnitin](https://www.turnitin.com/) service and I have tried to delete the question but I am unable to do so since a person already answered to it.

I have edited the post and removed my opinion and view that I have written and left the question with only a few words left. A moderator has edited my question and added all my text back and locked the question.

I was wondering how can I delete such question.
Also I have been told by the moderator to open a thread here in meta.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what the exact reason is you want it deleted? Did you use your own work from your own essay in a question you posted here? Or did you ask a question where you used the answer in your essay without attribution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't.  You've licence the content under the CC license, giving others the ability to publish that content so long as they meet certain criteria.  The content will only be removed if the site determines that it's not a useful contribution worth keeping, and it sound like that isn't the case, given that it apparently has generated answers others feel is useful.

You can flag the post and ask for it to be disassociated from your account, if you no longer wish you to have your name tied to that content (it's a right that you have under the terms of the license).

But for it to be deleted your only real choice is to convince a moderator or community members with the privilege to delete the post, that it's not actually useful and that we as a community shouldn't *want* it to be kept around.

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer. I would like to keep the question up because it has gotten very useful answers but the only problem is trying to prove to my professor that I did not plagiarize and that is my own work

Comment: @Hidaw That's pretty easily done.  Just ask your professor to put something in your profile (just have him pick some big number or a GUID or something like that to edit in), show him that said text is in your profile, and now he'll know that the account is yours

Comment: That is a great idea thank you very much for the help!!! really appreciate it!

Comment: Also note that in many academic contexts citation of your own published works still require citation to not be plagiarism, depending on the specific rules (and conventions) of the academic institution that you are in, the project you're working on, and the instructor.  The fact that you're re-using your own work doesn't necessarily mean it isn't plagiarism.

Comment: @Hidaw I edited the title of your question. I think that matches with what has been exchanged in the comments. Please check if you agree and I assume Servy will then move their relevant comment(s) into the answer.

Comment: @Hidaw you might also be interested in ["self-plagiarism" tag](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-plagiarism) on [Academia.SE] to handle this case.